# Auto login after successful registration doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm  trying to creating a auto login when the user has successfully registerd in.

This is the methode inside the controller but the second `logger.info(auth.toString());`is not displayed.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createaccount",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAccount(@ModelAttribute User user,BindingResult result){

    if (result.hasErrors()){

        return "newaccount";
    }

    if(usersService.exists(user.getEmail())){
        result.rejectValue("email","DuplicateKey.user.email");
        logger.info("caught duplicate email");
        return "newaccount";
    }

    user.setAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    user.setEnabled(true);
    usersService.create(user);


    // perform login authentication
    try {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsSvc.loadUserByUsername(user.getEmail());
        logger.info(userDetails);
        logger.info(userDetails.getAuthorities());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, user.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());

        logger.info(auth.toString());

        authMgr.authenticate(auth);

        logger.info(auth.toString());

        // redirect into secured main page if authentication successful
        if(auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            logger.info("auth isAuthenticated");
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            return "userlogin";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Problem authenticating user" + user.getEmail(), e);
    }

    return "accountcreated";
}
```

This is my logger info :

```
2015-08-12 14:11:20 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] INFO  LoginController:112 - org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@1ceaf: Username: xax; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
2015-08-12 14:11:20 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] INFO  LoginController:113 - [ROLE_USER]
2015-08-12 14:11:20 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] INFO  LoginController:116 - org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@441d0272: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@1ceaf: Username: xax; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
2015-08-12 14:11:20 [http-apr-8080-exec-1] INFO  TestFilter:25 - /createaccount
```

**Edit**

This is my solution :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createaccount",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAccount(@ModelAttribute User user,BindingResult result){

    if (result.hasErrors()){

        return "newaccount";
    }

    if(usersService.exists(user.getEmail())){
        result.rejectValue("email","DuplicateKey.user.email");
        logger.info("caught duplicate email");
        return "newaccount";
    }

    user.setAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    user.setEnabled(true);
    usersService.create(user);




    // perform login authentication
    try {
       UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsSvc.loadUserByUsername(user.getEmail());
        logger.info(userDetails);
        logger.info(userDetails.getAuthorities());
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, user.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());


        // redirect into secured main page if authentication successful
       if(auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            logger.info("auth isAuthenticated");
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            return "userlogin";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Problem authenticating user" + user.getEmail(), e);
    }

    return "accountcreated";
}
```

As you notice i removed the authMgr.authenticate(auth)
I guess this is no longer needed in spring 4. And now the users auto login after filling in the register form.
please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Can you add your spring security config file please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to authenticate the user in this way :

```
// Below method gets Person object from DB
Person person1 = this.personService.findPersonByUsername(useremail);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
// add the role in below line
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(person1, null, authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

let me know if this works.

Comment: This does't work either. I don't have a personService class. Also i already given the user a role when entering the db. Do you have some other suggestions?

Comment: You dont need to have a personservice class, just use whatever method you use to get the user from DB, and try it out. Change the role whichever you have configured to.

Comment: I got it working with removing authMgr.authenticate(auth); It produces the following error No AuthenticationProvider found. But for some reason i don't need this. I'm using spring 4. I'm glad it worked. But can you explain why ?

Comment: Good luck. Keep authenticating.. :D